How to have an object appear gradually based on position of several cylinders
I would like to do something similar to this.
I have a bunch of "sticks" on a tree branch that I will join together as a single object to make things easier.  I want the sticks to be invisible at first, then a flashlight turns on quickly to send a burst of light (a cylinder or cone, yellow, semi transparent) which will make visible only that section of the tree, which will now stay visible permanently. Note that the burst of light from the flashlight is not visible anymore at this point.  Then a different flashlight will light up a different section of the tree, and so on.
I was guessing I could have a bunch of empties (invisible cylinders, light bursts) which I could somehow use to control the visibility of nearby objects.
thanks!
thanks!
